# Image cropping with TinyMCE in Mosaico

Tags: mosaico, images, tinymce

Does anyone have image editing enabled in Mosaico through TinyMCE?

I assume it is possible through [Mosaico Toolbar Configurator](https://github.com/ginkgostreet/com.ginkgostreet.mosaicotoolbarconfig).

Additionally, what would be truly wonderful is if there was a way to crop images within Mosaico to a specific aspect ratio. One big problem we have is users who are unable or unwilling to crop images on their computer, especially to a specified aspect ratio. If there were some way to make this possible in Mosaico, that would save a lot of headache.

As far as I can tell, this isn't possible in TinyMCE image editor. In MoxieManager for TinyMCE, it is in theory possible to specify the width of an image and then crop to a specific height, but that relies on either carefully selecting exactly the height you want or entering it (which doesn't allow you to select the image area to crop to).

Answer (score 1):

I implemented an image editor which you can grab here: https://github.com/lcdservices/biz.lcdservices.mosaicoimageeditor

I built it for a specific client and have not yet tested how portable it is in other installations. But at the very least it should get you started.

Actually -- just reviewing it, and the method for storing the image via API is client specific. At some point I'll generalize it so it's useful for the community. It implements: https://github.com/scaleflex/filerobot-image-editor